# libev with two ev_timer 100%CPU utiluzed

Tags: cpu, libev

first,my english is very bad...
this is my code:

```
ev_timer_init(&m_netmsgpoptimer, netMsgTimer_cb, 10, 10.);
ev_timer_start(m_loop, &m_netmsgpoptimer);

m_mainlooptimer.data = (void*)this;
// 
ev_timer_init(&m_mainlooptimer, mainloopTimer_cb, 20, 20.);
ev_timer_start(m_loop, &m_mainlooptimer);

ev_loop(m_loop, 0);
```

and this is perf said:

```
5504.368980 task-clock                #    0.999 CPUs utilized
```

the perf cpu-clock record like this:

```
+  30.08%  huhuGame  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] mutex_lock                             ◆
+  29.40%  huhuGame  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] memcpy                                 ▒
+   4.75%  huhuGame  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] system_call_after_swapgs               ▒
```

if i changed my code line "ev_loop(m_loop, 0)" to this:

```
    timespec  _tstart, _tend;
while(!m_bExit)
{
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &_tstart);
    ev_loop(m_loop, EVLOOP_ONESHOT);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &_tend);
    long long  t1, t2;
    t1 =   _tstart.tv_sec*10000+_tstart.tv_nsec/100000;
    t2 =  _tend.tv_sec*10000 + _tend.tv_nsec/100000;
    t1 =  (t2 - t1)*10;
    if(t1 < 100)
        usleep(100-t1);
}
```

cpu utiluze is low..
and why ev_loop(m_loop,0) with ev_time will cost 100% cpu performance?

any answer is helpful,thanks!

Comment: The english language knowledge is an important key to communicate in technical community.

Comment: I guess that the problem might be elsewhere. What are the other events you are looping on? Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) and also `strace`

Comment: i am trying to improve...it's a little hard for me.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch i used perf record again for a long elapse,reprot is different

Comment: +  30.08%  huhuGame  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] mutex_lock    29.40%  huhuGame  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] memcpy    +   4.75%  huhuGame  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] system_call_after_swapgs               ▒

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch you are right,there is a module hiredis async,it used libev too,it's ok when i commented it.

Comment: Try using ev_run(m_loop, 0), ev_loop is deprecated in libev 4.x.